# Redirect Wordpress From a Old URL to a new URL excluding Admin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect Wordpress website from an old domain to a new domain except the admin. I have done this so far, it's currently redirecting all urls including the admin to the new website

```
#Wildcard Redirect
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldwebsite.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldwebsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-login
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newwebsite..com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```